# SQL server udf not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm now all day on a fairly simple udf. It's below. When I paste the select statement into a query, it runs as expected... when I execute the entire function, I get "0" every time. As you know there aren't a ton of debugging options, so it's hard to see what value are/ aren't being set as it executes. The basic purpose of it is to make sure stock data exists in a daily pricing table. So I can check by how many days' data I'm checking for, the ticker, and the latest trading date to check. A subquery gets me the correct trading dates, and I use "IN" to pull data out of the pricing and vol table... if the count of what comes back is less than the number of days I'm checking, no good. If it does, we're in business. Any help would be great, I'm a newb that is punting at this point:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.PricingVolDataAvailableToDateProvided
    (@Ticker char,
     @StartDate DATE,
     @NumberOfDaysBack int)
    RETURNS bit
AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result bit
    DECLARE @RecordCount int

SET @RecordCount = (
    SELECT COUNT(TradeDate) AS Expr1
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT TradeDate
            FROM   tblDailyPricingAndVol
            WHERE  ( Symbol = @Ticker )
                   AND ( TradeDate IN (SELECT TOP (@NumberOfDaysBack)
                                      CAST(TradingDate AS DATE) AS Expr1
                                       FROM   tblTradingDays
                                       WHERE  ( TradingDate <= @StartDate )
                                       ORDER  BY TradingDate DESC) )
            ORDER  BY TradeDate DESC) AS TempTable ) 

    IF @RecordCount = @NumberOfDaysBack
        SET @Result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 0

    RETURN @Result

    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Ticker char` seems suspect.

If you don't declare a length in the parameter definition it defaults to `char(1)` so quite likely your passed in tickers are being silently truncated - hence no matches.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT TradeDate ... ORDER  BY TradeDate DESC
```

in the derived table is pointless but won't affect the result.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still pulling hair out :)

Comment: Well have you fixed the issue with `char`? If so what did you change the parameter definition too? What is the datatype of `tblDailyPricingAndVol.Symbol`? How are you calling it?

Comment: Not fixed yet. I changed the parameter def to: "@Ticker nchar(10)" which is the datatype in the table.

Comment: I'm just testing it in the sql enviroment/ functionality in VS2010. (right click>execute)

Comment: YES! And right you were to ask. Very stupid mistake. I was putting single quotes around my tickers when entering them in the parameters dialog. Learning curves can be painful. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh Easy mistake to make, no worries!